# dependent select options one on another one

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

Good morning all, 
i have a piece of code which looks heavy for me, i would like to go with light code. my task is about to select states and the cities using two dropdown boxes. i need to change city dropdown box with respect to states dropdown box, help me on this

here my code:::

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Compare To</legend>
    <span>state</span><select id="locationId" name="locationId">
    <option value="0" <c:if test="${loc.location eq '0'}">selected="selected"</c:if>>All Locations</option> 
    <c:forEach items="${locationDetailsList}" var="locationDetails">
        <option value="${locationDetails.locationId}" <c:if test="${loc.locationId2 eq locationDetails.locationId}">
        selected="selected"</c:if>>${locationDetails.locationName}</option>
    </c:forEach></select>

    <span>area</span> 
    <select id="area" name="area">
        <option value="0" <c:if test="${locationId eq '0'}">selected="selected"</c:if>>All Locations</option> 
        <option value="1" <c:if test="${locationId ge '1'}">selected="selected"</c:if>>Hyderabad</option>
        <option value="1" <c:if test="${locationId ge '1'}">selected="selected"</c:if>>Vizag</option>
    </select> 
</fieldset>
```

thx in advance dear frnds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer to this question: [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3342984/1065197), *[JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) tags (...) are executed during view build time*, this means that they are evaluated only one time when building the HTML to be rendered to the client.

Knowing this, you can only update the data in your `<select id="area">` only by doing a full request/response to the server to load the values based on the value of your `<select id="locationId">` component.

In this times, it's heavily painful to make users get a totally new response just with the elements of a dropdownlist, so you can use an Ajax approach as shown here: [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/1065197) Note that BalusC even writes a full example about building an `<option>` list based on a `Map<String, String>` in the *Here's another example which displays `Map<String, String>` as `<option>`* part.

Remember that for the ajax solution, your `<select id="area">` should not have any JSTL tag inside, it should not have any element at all:

```
<select id="area">
</select>
```